# React JS - TextInput closes automatically when opened on android

Tags: reactjs, textinput

TextInput closes automatically when opened on android except chrome browser.

I have searched the internet and found nothing. All are talking for react-native but I want the solution for react -JS.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.